# Graphing Piecewise Linear Convex Function

Tags: linear-programming

In the lecturer's notes, we say the $$\max_{i = 1,\ldots, m}(c_i^T x + d_i) $$ is a piecewise linear convex function and the notation $$\max_{i = 1,\ldots,m} $$ for the maximum value among $a_1, a_1,\ldots, a_m$

How do you sketch the graph $$y = \max(2x, 1-x, 1+x)$$
So confused right here. I can sketch the individual components, but how do I find the max of each them separately..?

Comment: Draw the three curves, then the max is always the top most one at any point. For example, $|x| = \max(x,-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment : Draw the three curves, then the max is always the top most one at any point. For example, $|x| = \max(x,-x)$.

Comment: ok I think I need to work on basics. Like So I drew |x|  = max(x, -x)
and I get  2 curves along the origin for y = x and y = -x. So what is top most one at any point supposed to mean here. Not sure how to use that to draw V - shaped absolute value from max.

Comment: Are you saying the very top part of the curves joining together is the max? So I would sketch the top V part of y  = x and y = -x joining together?

Comment: @llllllllllllllllllllllllllllll : When you draw a graph, for each number $x$ on the $x$-axis there is a corresponding $y$-value, which in your case is the largest of $2x$, $1-x$, and $1+x$.  Through the point $x$ on the $x$-axis the vertical line you see on the graph paper has three points whose $y$-coordinates are $2x$, $1-x$, and $1+x$.  The one corresponding to the largest number is the highest one. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ohhh I get what you mean now. Thanks a lot for the help everyone!